# Fixing a couple of odd problems after I dropped my MacBook

Tags: macbook-pro

I dropped my MacBook (six years old, running OS X 10.6.8) on the ground, and have observed a couple of odd problems since then:

- Whenever I open my MacBook it attempts to eject the CD, makes a couple of violent-sounding noises, fails, and gives up. (Also, the software no longer recognizes that there is a CD in the drive.) Whenever I try software solutions (e.g. drutil tray eject) it does the same.
- Occasionally, roughly every two or three minutes, the computer freezes for about ten seconds. When it does this it often highlights the "File" option in the menu at the top.

Otherwise my MacBook works fine. Anyone know how I might fix these issues? (Especially the second, if I busted my CD drive I can live with that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It sounds like the CD drive is broken.
- A sign of potential future HDD failure. Does the drive make any clicking noises or any strange sounds? I'd make a full backup and prepare for the worst, especially considering the age of the machine.